# how to detect and reflect the ball from the left or right edge of the paddle in classic brick breaker (using javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, collision-detection, collision, game-development

Only to simply, I have a square box which moves in only the horizontal direction and a ball that can reflect from all the edges. I know the codes for reflecting the ball from the top position, the only problem is that I can't reflect the ball from the right or left edges. From hours of debugging, I got to 
know that with the initial value of the `X` coordinate of the corner of the square, the ball reflects till I disturb or change it with the mouse, then only the ball passes through the square.

For the left or right edges, I have tried using the method used in the pong game but it just doesn't work, maybe because of the square moves in the `X`  direction, while in pong it doesn't.

```
function paddle_edge(){
if(bally>paddleY && bally<paddleY+paddleThick){
    if (ballx==paddleX||ballx==paddleX+paddleLen) {
         ballspeedx = -ballspeedx;
         ballspeedy=-ballspeedy; }
   }
}
```

Comment: You'll probably need to use inequalities as well, like for the Y coordinate. `ballx + ballSize >= paddleX && ballx <= paddleX + paddleLen`. You'll also probably only want to invert the y speed in this case rather than both (if your paddle is at the top or bottom)

Comment: I don't think you want to reverse both x and y ballspeed at the same time.

Comment: It's a brick breaker game, if it hits the right or left edge it should bounce back in the opposite direction so reversing both of them is necessary.

Comment: Yeah I tried with the inequalities too, but no result in favour. Probably as I said it's something to do with the updation of x coordinate of paddle.